# incompatible types error. Java?

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

I am trying to return an integer in java but it gives me the incompatible types error.

```
public int getNubers(){
 if (counter.getValue()% 9 == 0) 
 {
     return "counter.getValue/9";
 }
}
```

Comment: public int return int not string..public String return String

Comment: I wonder what a "nuber" is. Is it kind of like a number, but with the "m", whatever that means?

Answer (score 5):

Your function has a declared return type of `int`, but you are attempting to return a string. Give this a try:

```
public String getNubers(){
 if (counter.getValue()% 9 == 0) 
 {
     return "counter.getValue/9";
 }
 return "OOPS"; //gotta return something here.
}
```

Alternatively, I think you're actually trying to do this:

```
public int getNubers(){
 if (counter.getValue()% 9 == 0) 
 {
     return counter.getValue() / 9 ;
 }
 return -1; //bloop bleep
}
```

Comment: `hans lepoeter` is right in his answer. That code won't compile, because there's no `return` statement after the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are partially wrong either way. If you have a function returning something you SHOULD return it no matter what. So just returning the integer in case the division returns a whole number is not an option.

You could assign an error value in case the devision is not a whole number, say -1, then return that at the end of the function, meaning the division returns not a whole number.

You could also throw an exception in case the division does not result in a whole number.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you hans that is very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

`"counter.getValue/9"` is a string not int.
it should be

```
return counter.getValue()/9;
```